OCP protection circuit


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I wanted a project to learn stuff and test my own skills, so I started to design a DC electronic load. For this project I imposed myself some specification:

Min DUT voltage:  3V
Max DUT voltage:  60V
Max DUT current:  4A
trip time:  1-2 us
quiescent current draw from the DUT:  5mA

For the protection circuit part I could have used an efuse chip but like I said it's for learning so I decided to do it with discrete components. I also tried to use a NMOS driver but it seems to me that all of them are built to work in continuous switching.
In LTspice this circuit works but i have 2 problems:

if the DUT is low voltage like 3,7V battery there isn't enough VGS
on the mosfets and they don't turn on (note: i already have -12V
avaible in the rest of the circuit) so aso PUR/PDR has to be a high
ratio

i want the circuit to accept also high voltage so i had to protect the gates from the high voltage
with a zener but when the 2n7000 is on the current in PUR and the
zener is too high (2W dissipation). Also i can't make PUR and PDR
higher otherwise the trip time of M2 will be to slow


Sorry the circuit doesn't work in circuitlab, i don't know how to use it and i don't know what's wrong, anyway i link the LTSPICE file, also i link the source of the latch comparator and the protection circuit. Thanks in advance
I add a screenshot of the circuit to facilitate those who read from smartphones


so, you need to start with a specification. "As good as I can" is not something we could help you with! You need to really write down what you want that thing to do. If it's too easy, fine, you can later on make it harder. But not having a specification and random problems arising from trying to do something that you didn't write down is sadly really impossible to assist you with.

okay, you're right, i would like a trip time in the order of some us, a min DUT voltage of 3V, a max DUT voltage of 60V and a low bias current from the DUT, something like tens of mA, the overall project will be capable of 4A. I add this information in the main post

voted to reopen.
